# Get source slow in CI when a website project contains a lot of small images

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration

I have a website project with a lot of small images (more than 15000), every time CI tools get source code from TFS will take a very long time. If there is a solution can avoid this?

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the SkipClean and SkipInitializeWorkspace properties. [This](http://blog.deploymentengineering.com/2007/06/smarter-tfs-incremental-builds.html) is a cleanest solution. These will manipulate the IncrementalGet and IncrementalBuild properties correctly.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833876.aspx) and [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsbuild/thread/6322a635-5810-4977-9830-d0dd5bd4d0c1) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are doing an update, not a full/fresh checkout every time.  Then you will only pay the price to update the changed file(s), not fetch the entire set of files.

The [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/)'s [SVN plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Subversion+Plugin) has a checkbox for "Use Update"

> If checked, Hudson will use 'svn
>   update' whenever possible, making the
>   build faster. But this causes the
>   artifacts from the previous build to
>   remain when a new build starts.